# Number is not incrementing using stored procedure in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have data in my `CaseFiles` table `csfl_CaseNo` column as

```
00001/13-14
00002/13-14
00003/13-14
00004/13-14
00005/13-14
```

Here is my stored procedure to increment the number

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HLA_CaseNo](@strFnyr as nvarchar(5),@strSuffix as nvarchar(15) OUTPUT) 
AS
BEGIN
--Declarations
declare @strSuffix1 as nvarchar(15)
declare @strTmp as nvarchar(5)
declare @intNew as int
--declare @strSql as nvarchar(2000)
set @strSuffix1 = null  
  --Process
begin
    set @strSuffix1 = (select max(csfl_caseNo) from CaseFiles where csfl_Fynyr = @strFnyr)
    --set @strPrf='QUT'
end

if @strSuffix1 is null
    set @intNew = 1
else
    set @intNew = cast(substring(@strSuffix1,0,5) as int) + 1

print 'The value of intNew ' + cast(@intNew as nvarchar(10))
set @strTmp = cast(@intNew as nvarchar(5))
set @strTmp = (select replicate('0',5-len(@strTmp)) + @strTmp)
set @strSuffix = @strTmp + '/' + @strFnyr
```

END

My task is when I pass the financial year as `13-14`  it has to return the value as `00006/13-14`, but it is returning `00002/13-14` instead.

Why this is happening? Please help

Comment: Besides your existing bug you also have a multi-user issue. When two different users call this stored procedure they will be assigned the same number. If you're using SQL Server 2012, use a `SEQUENCE` instead. If you're using an earlier version use an `IDENTITY`. With regards to your bug, without knowing whats in the `csfl_Fynyr` field no one can help. In the meantime, why don't you echo all of your variable values using `PRINT` or `SELECT` and inspect them. You probably have an offset wrong or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
set @intNew = cast(substring(@strSuffix1,0,5) as int) + 1
```

to

```
set @intNew = cast(substring(@strSuffix1,1,5) as int) + 1
```

OR even rather use

```
LEFT(@strSuffix1,5)
```

rather than

```
substring(@strSuffix1,1,5)
```

so, something like

```
set @intNew = cast(LEFT(@strSuffix1,5) as int) + 1
```

From [SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

> start
>
> Is an integer or bigint expression that specifies where the returned
>   characters start. If start is less than 1, the returned expression
>   will begin at the first character that is specified in expression.
>   **In this case, the number of characters that are returned is the largest value of either the sum of start + length- 1 or 0**. If start
>   is greater than the number of characters in the value expression, a
>   zero-length expression is returned.

So that would imply `start + length- 1 = 0 + 5 - 1 = 4`, which would imply `cast(substring(@strSuffix1,0,5) as int)` is 0, and `set @intNew = cast(substring(@strSuffix1,0,5) as int) + 1` = 1

Comment: Good eye, and great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that...

```
set @strSuffix1 = (select max(csfl_caseNo) from CaseFiles where csfl_Fynyr = @strFnyr)
```

...is setting @strSuffix1 to `null` because no there is no `CaseFiles` record `where csfl_Fynyr = @strFnyr`.

Check that you are trimming `csfl_Fynyr` and `@strFnyr` if appropriate - possible mismatch on trailing whitespace you have missed.

To debug just that statement, take the value that you are passing for `@strFnyr` and replace `@strFnyr` in the statement with the value in single quotes: run it on its own to see whether you actually get a `max(csfl_caseNo)` value back.

Comment: sorry sir..... I have a csfl_Fynyr field which has 13-14..  and @strSuffix1 is not returning to NULL.. It is taking max value exactly

Comment: Thanks for the reality check.  That is just the possibility that stood out to me initially.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it more succinct with one statement

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000' + CAST(LEFT(MAX(csfl_CaseNo), 5) + 1 AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) + '/13-14'
  FROM CaseFiles
 WHERE RIGHT(csfl_CaseNo, 5) = '13-14';
```

Then your SP might look like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE HLA_CaseNo(@strFnyr as nvarchar(5), @strSuffix as nvarchar(15) OUTPUT) 
AS
SELECT @strSuffix = RIGHT('0000' + CAST(LEFT(MAX(csfl_CaseNo), 5) + 1 AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) + '/' + @strFnyr
  FROM CaseFiles
 WHERE RIGHT(csfl_CaseNo, 5) = @strFnyr;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c342/1)**